# How to manually grey out item in Beamer enumeration

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, enumerate, transition

How do I manually specify that the first item in the list should be greyed out?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First section
\item Second section
\item Third section
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm creating an outline manually and thus would like to grey out the sections in the outline that has already been covered.

Comment: What's wrong with `\item {\color{gray}First section}`?

Comment: This feels like an xy-problem. Why not use beamers build in toc mechanism?

Comment: Of course, that is another possibility. But that typically opens an other can of worms. So i built my toc manually, and was surprised to learn that there is no simple way to manually gray out items. @JouleV solutions works, but it is not the same grey that is applied when uncovering.

Comment: @arvixx You can of course use other grays, for example `gray!20!` or `black!40`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure that there might be a better solution then this one!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]\color{gray}
\item \color<.>{black}First section
\item \color<.>{black}Second section
\item \color<.>{black}Third section
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**An other version with only two slides**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item \textcolor<2->{gray}{First section}
       \item<2->Second section
       \item <2->Third section
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THanks for your answer. However, what I want is actually /only/ the second slide, i.e. where the first item is grey and the remaining are visible and in the normal text color.

Comment: @arvixx answer updated!

Comment: Is there a way to grey out also the item symbol? Thanks

Comment: @user3285148 I don't know how it can be done! I encourage you to post a new question so it can be seen by other members